# How to use a UDF value or column value in hive insert partition statement, rather than constant value

Tags: hive, hive-partitions

I have a data table created as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `DailyData`(
  `entity_id` string,
  `payload` string)
PARTITIONED BY 
  (`date_of_data` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0010'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/home/data/dailydata'
```

I have a job run daily to insert data into to `daily_table`

It can works using the following statement

```
INSERT INTO TABLE DailyData partition(date_of_data="20181126") 
SELECT id as entity_id, simpledata as payload from log_data;
```

My expectation is it can automatically using the current day instead of using a hardcode date string ( like 20181126")

I tried

```
INSERT INTO TABLE DailyData partition(date_of_data=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyyMMdd')) 
SELECT id as entity_id, simpledata as payload from log_data;
```

And got the following exception

```
    NoViableAltException(26@[244:1: constant : ( Number | dateLiteral | timestampLiteral | intervalLiteral | StringLiteral | stringLiteralSequence | BigintLiteral | SmallintLiteral | TinyintLiteral | DecimalLiteral | charSetStringLiteral | booleanValue );])
            at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
            at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:116)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.constant(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:4928)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.partitionVal(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10726)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.partitionSpec(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10560)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.tableOrPartition(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10438)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tableOrPartition(HiveParser.java:49929)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.insertClause(HiveParser.java:46629)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:43233)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:42451)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:42321)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1681)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1152)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:211)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:171)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:447)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:330)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1233)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1274)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1170)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1160)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:217)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:169)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:380)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:740)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:685)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
    FAILED: ParseException line 1:65 cannot recognize input near 'from_unixtime' '(' 'unix_timestamp' in constant
```

And I tried

```
INSERT INTO TABLE DailyData partition(date_of_data=data_of_date) 
SELECT id as entity_id, simpledata as payload, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyyMMdd') as data_of_date from log_data;
```

Got the similar exception.

```
NoViableAltException(26@[244:1: constant : ( Number | dateLiteral | timestampLiteral | intervalLiteral | StringLiteral | stringLiteralSequence | BigintLiteral | SmallintLiteral | TinyintLiteral | DecimalLiteral | charSetStringLiteral | booleanValue );])
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.constant(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:4928)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.partitionVal(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10726)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.partitionSpec(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10560)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.tableOrPartition(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tableOrPartition(HiveParser.java:49929)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.insertClause(HiveParser.java:46629)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:43233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:42451)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:42321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1681)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:447)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:380)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:51 cannot recognize input near 'date_of_data' ')' 'SELECT' in constant
```

Is it doable to use a value in partition statement rather than constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;` and giving partition value as part-of the select statement.
Note the last column in `select` clause is `date_of_data` and by specifying `partition(date_of_data)` this columns is used as partition value.
**warning** if there is multiple values in the partition the records will be sent to corresponding partition. Use with caution.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
INSERT INTO TABLE DailyData partition(date_of_data) 
SELECT id as entity_id, simpledata as payload, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyyMMdd') as date_of_data from log_data;
```

Reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+dml#LanguageManualDML-DynamicPartitionInserts